# Accessing Public DNS on AWS with Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I've installed and started Redis on an AWS ec2 instance(linux) but when I try to access it from the Public DNS, it can't load the page. I updated the Redis.conf to bind my specific IP address but to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions on what I'm missing? Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the answers below I was able to learn that Redis is in fact NOT a web server BUT it is used as a database, which is where I think my confusion came from. Feel free to learn more here: https://redis.io

Comment: What do you mean by _"it can't load the page"_? If you're trying to access Redis from a web browser then you're using it wrong.

Comment: xref: https://www.reddit.com/r/redis/comments/af7tee/redis_and_aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is not a web server - you can connect to it with one of the [available clients](https://redis.io/clients) or via TCP (e.g. telnet).